# How to change and blink the title of the browser when the user goes to other tab or minimizes the browser?

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to change the title of the browser and set it to  a blinking text when the user opens another tab or just minimizes the browser.

Comment: use document.title to change title

Comment: You cannot just blink it, you need to set it to an empty string then back to make it "blink".

Comment: Each time you have to make it blank and then reset the title to make some kind of blinking effect

Comment: but how to do it if user moves to other tab?

Answer (score 1):

For blinking the title:

```
var title = document.title;
var intv = window.setInterval(function () {
    document.title = document.title === '' ? title : '';
}, 500);

// call this to stop the blinking
function stopBlink() {
    window.clearInterval(intv);
    document.title = title;
}
```

---

As for doing it on tab switch or minimize, **maybe** running the code on `window.onblur` would work but I'm guessing it can't be done.